# Add row after click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi gladly I want to add a task row after I have clicked the save button. However what I have tried didn't seem to work unfortunately.

To show you the problem that I have. I will show you through a video where I have recorded myself. Here is the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d7L75HflxYo&feature=youtu.be

This is what I have tried:

```
        var orderId=$('#id_order').val();

        var $table = $('#taskTable');
        $table.empty();
        loadOrderTable(orderId);
```

And I have also tried this:

```
        var orderId=$('#id_order').val();

        var $table = $('#taskTable');
        $table.empty();
        //loadOrderTable(orderId);

        $table.html(loadOrderTable(orderId));
```

Both attemps were placed in the body of the click function $('#saveOrder').click(function(e).

Now I will show you there rest of my code, in case if you need it.

```
$(function(){ 

    $('#saveOrder').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $('#orderForm');

        var allInput=form.serialize();
        //var allInputJSON = JSON.stringify(allInput);

        console.log('form serialize value:  '+form.serialize());
        //console.log('allInputJSON value:  '+allInputJSON);

        $.ajax( {
               url: absUrl + "/user/orders/update/ordertasks",
                data: {'allInput' : allInput},
              success: function( response ) {
              console.log('response value:  '+ response );

              //tried this after a user has added a task and that the gets filled with the new added row. But unfortunately it doesn't works.
                var orderId=$('#id_order').val();           
                var $table = $('#taskTable');
                $table.empty();
                loadOrderTable(orderId);
              }
        } );

    });

    //addRowOnTaskTable(6);
    var orderId=$('#id_order').val();
    loadOrderTable(orderId);
    //updateTotal();
    //absUrl is declared in user/_layouts/template_head.blade.php

    function loadOrderTable(order_id){
        var order_id=order_id;


        $.ajax({

          url: absUrl+"/user/orders/load/tasks",
          data: {'order_id' : order_id}
        }).done(function(data) {

            var data = $.parseJSON(data);

            console.log('result loading table');

            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

            $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                    $('#taskTable').append(
                        '<tr>'+
                            '<td>'
                                +value.task_name+
                            '</td>'+
                            '<td>'
                                +value.task_hour+
                            '</td>'+
                            '<td>'+     //pak load id ordertask ipv load hour voor je backend
                                '<input type="text" class="form-control hour" id="hour'+value.id+'" name="load_hour[]" value='+value.hour+' data-row='+value.id+'  style="max-width:50%" placeholder="">'+
                            '</td>'+
                            '<td>'+
                                '<input type="text" class="form-control hour_salary" id="hour_salary'+value.id+'" name="load_hour_salaries[]" value='+value.hourprice+' data-row='+value.id+' style="max-width:50%" placeholder="">'+
                            '</td>'+
                            '<td>'+
                                '<input type="text" class="form-control"  id="total_salary'+value.id+'" name="load_total_salaries[]" value='+value.totalprice+' readonly   style="max-width:50%" placeholder="">'+
                            '</td>'+
                            '<td>'+
                                '<div class="dropdown">'+
                                    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle selDelete" data-toggle="dropdown">'+
                                        '<input id="check1" name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" class="check" >'+
                                        '<span class="caret-hover caret"></span>'+
                                    '</button>'+

                                   ' <input type="hidden" name="load_id_task[]" value="'+value.id_task+'"/>'+
                                   ' <input type="hidden" name="load_id_ordertask[]" value="'+value.id+'"/>'+

                                    '<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="selDelete" role="menu">'+
                                        '<li><a class="deleteOrdertask" id="deleteOrdertask' + value.id + '"  value="deleteOrdertask' + value.id + '" data-row='+value.id+' href= "#" data-method="delete" >Delete</a></li>'+
                                    '</ul>'+   
                                 '</div>'
                            +'</td>'+
                        '</tr>');

             }); 

            $('.deleteOrdertask').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var $this = $(this);
                var rowId = $this.data('row');
                deleteOtRow( rowId );

            });

            var deleteOtRow = function(rowId){
                $deleteOrdertask =  $("#deleteOrdertask" + rowId);
                $($deleteOrdertask).parents('tr').remove();

                var temp = $('#delete_ordertasks').val();

                $('#delete_ordertasks').val(temp + rowId + ",");

                //$(this).parents('tr').remove();
            };



            var updateTotal = function(rowId){
                var rowId = rowId,
                    $hour_salary =  $("#hour_salary" + rowId),
                    $total_salary =  $("#total_salary" + rowId);

                var hour = parseFloat($("#hour" + rowId).val()),
                    hour_salary = parseFloat($hour_salary.val()); 

                if ( hour_salary.length > 0 ) 
                    $total_salary.val("0"); 
                else
                    $total_salary.val( hour_salary * hour );
            };
            //updates elke totaal veld zonder dat een user een knop heeft ingedrukt.
            $('.hour_salary').each(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                updateTotal($this.data('row'));
            });

            $(".hour_salary").keyup(function() { 
                console.log('test keyup ');
                var $this = $(this);
                var rowId = $this.data('row');
                $this.val( $this.val().replace(/\D/g,'') );
                updateTotal( rowId );  
            });

            $(".hour").keyup(function() { 
                var $this = $(this);
                var rowId = $this.data('row');
                $this.val( $this.val().replace(/\D/g,'') );
                updateTotal( rowId );
            });


        });


    }




    function addRowOnTaskTable( id_task ){
        var id_task=id_task;
        console.log('addrow id '+ id_task);

        $.ajax({    
          url: absUrl+"/user/orders/post/task",
          data: {'id_task' : id_task}
        }).done(function(data) {    
            var data = $.parseJSON(data);   
            console.log('add row JSON stringify'+JSON.stringify(data));

                    $('#taskTable').append(
                        '<tr>'+
                            '<td>'
                                +data.task_name+
                            '</td>'+
                            '<td>'
                                +data.task_hour+
                            '</td>'+
                            '<td>'+
                                '<input type="text" class="form-control hour" value="" data-row="'+data.id+'" name="hour[]" style="max-width:50%" placeholder="">'+
                            '</td>'+
                            '<td>'+
                                '<input type="text" class="form-control hour_salary" value="" data-row='+data.id+' name="hour_salary[]" style="max-width:50%" placeholder="">'+
                            '</td>'+
                            '<td>'+
                                '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="total_salary[]" value="" readonly  style="max-width:50%" placeholder="">'+
                            '</td>'+
                            '<td>'+
                                '<div class="dropdown">'+
                                    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle selDelete" data-toggle="dropdown">'+
                                        '<input id="check1" name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" class="check" >'+
                                        '<span class="caret-hover caret"></span>'+
                                    '</button>'+

                                   ' <input type="hidden" name="id_task[]" value="'+data.id+'"/>'+
                                   ' <input type="hidden" name="id_ordertask[]" value=""/>'+
                                   ' <input type="hidden" name="id_task[]" value="'+data.id+'"/>'+

                                    '<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="selDelete" role="menu">'+
                                        '<li><a class="deleteOrdertask' + data.id + '" href= "'+absUrl+"/user/orders/delete/ordertask"+'" data-method="delete" >Delete</a></li>'+
                                    '</ul>'+   
                                 '</div>'
                            +'</td>'+
                        '</tr>'); 

                    $('.deleteOrdertask' + data.id ).click(function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $(this).parents('tr').remove();
                    });

                    var updateTotal = function(rowId){
                        var rowId = rowId,
                            $hour_salary =  $("#hour_salary" + rowId),
                            $total_salary =  $("#total_salary" + rowId);

                        var hour = parseFloat($("#hour" + rowId).val()),
                            hour_salary = parseFloat($hour_salary.val()); 

                        if ( hour_salary.length > 0 ) 
                            $total_salary.val("0"); 
                        else
                            console.log('tot ja  '+ hour_salary * hour);
                            $total_salary.val( hour_salary * hour );
                    };

                    $(".hour_salary").keyup(function() { 
                        console.log('test keyup ');
                        var $this = $(this);
                        var rowId = $this.data('row');               
                        $this.val( $this.val().replace(/\D/g,'') );
                        updateTotal( rowId );
                    });

                    $(".hour").keyup(function() { 
                        var $this = $(this);
                        var rowId = $this.data('row');
                        $this.val( $this.val().replace(/\D/g,'') );
                        updateTotal( rowId );
                    });
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: Do you have any errors on your browser console? Checking your code with [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) already revealed 12 warnings, include inappropriate linebreaks.

Comment: This could be helpful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery

Comment: @Terry Only 1 back-end error when saving the task and before doing a refresh. See here a screenshot link: http://i.imgur.com/yl64q9J.png  And after a refresh you the two tasks and I see 1 front-end error in my console. See here a screenshot link: http://i.imgur.com/LszKAYH.png

Comment: You are getting an internal server error, so no data is being returned from your AJAX call.

Comment: Yes it was indeed a back-end error which I have fixed today thanks Terry :).